# Angular datatable get selected row class

Tags: angular, angular6, getelementsbytagname, angular-datatables

I am using angular datatables with angular 6 with the row select extension and check class option, so that my table has a first column with a css checkbox. What I want is to determine whether the click event was to check or uncheck the box, which I thought should be possible by seeing if the current row's css class contains "selected".

I'm able to get to the class list for that particular row, and I thought logging `classList.length` would be 1 for not selected (just an "even" or "odd" class) and 2 for selected ("even selected" or "odd selected"). However, what I'm seeing is that it's showing the "selected" class on uncheck instead of check.

[image]

dtOptions:

```js
columnDefs: [ {
    orderable: false,
    className: 'select-checkbox',
    targets:   0,
    defaultContent: ''
  }],
  select: {
    style:    'os',
    selector: 'td:first-child'
  },
```

When the user clicks on `td:first-child` it will "check" or "uncheck" using css `::before` and `::after`, and in my row callback I'm only executing a handler function if the user clicked on that first cell and not any other cell.

```js
rowCallback: (row: Node, data: any[] | Object, index: number) => {
    const self = this;

    // Unbind first in order to avoid any duplicate handler
    // (see https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/87)
    $('td:first-child', row).unbind('click');
    $('td:first-child', row).bind('click', () => {
      self.someClickHandler(row, data, index);
    });
    return row;
  }
```

Then inside the handler function:

```js
let nodeList : NodeList = row.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("tr");
let elementList : Array<HTMLElement> = [];

if (nodeList) {
  for (let i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    let node : Node = nodeList[i];

    // Make sure it's really an Element
    if (node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        elementList.push(node as HTMLElement);
    }
 }
}

console.log(elementList[index].classList.length);
```

I'm not sure why I'm seeing the reverse of what I expect - I'd appreciate any insight. :)

Comment: I have a doubt in this. Whether the 'rowCallback' method called on each row click? In my case I did not get the event